# How to give forward slash in postman url as a parameter

Tags: url, postman, slash

This the controller calls having path variable.

```
@RequestHapping(value="/circuit/getCircuitDetails/{circuitid:.+}", method =RequestMethod.GET, produces "application/json") 

public ResponseEntity<ResponsePayLoad> getCircuitDetails (HttpServletRequest request, **@PathVariable (value = "circuitId" String circuitid**) throws Exception {
```

If I give path variable CircuitId as `N1036596/N1036597` in postman url -> that is string containing forward slash
`http://localhost:77/enggnar/circuit/getCircuitDetails/N1036596/N1036597`
It is giving me error in postman.

Even by giving `%2F` and `%5c` in place of slash is also not working for me.
Please help me how to give the pathvariable containing forward slash.